# Sortable and selectable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, selectable

Is there a way to use both sortable and selectable on same element?
I found [this](http://jsbin.com/aweyo5) solution, but it is based on 'handle', which I would like to avoid, since I want whole `li` to be both selectable and sortable. 
I'm working with Angular, so if there is an angular solution, even better.

Comment: From a user perspective making it too easy to drag items is a bad thing. Using a specific handle is generally better than allowing the entire item to be dragged. Dragging happens too easily with touch devices making the interface ugly when drags accidentally start. My advice: stick with a drag handle for reordering.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately, that's the requirement, so I have to stick to that.